# How to calculate average value for summary report?

Tags: formula, reporting

I am building a report on user's login rate which should calculate how much times a user logged in per working days in a month, applied formula "User Login Rate" to get a login rate value per each user:

`LOGIN_DATE:UNIQUE/PARENTGROUPVAL(LOGIN_DATE:UNIQUE, LOGIN_DATE)`

*Specific Groups: Username

E. g. there are 13 working days in the current month. The first user logged in 2 times, and the second user logged in every day. Therefore, the report shows 2/13*100% = 15,38% for the first user, and 100% for the second user.
[image: Text]

But I also need to get the average login rate for all users in a department. Subtotals seem not to be calculated in case of groups. How to get the average value for summary report in Salesforce?

Thank you.